# how can add new package in java to another package?

Tags: java, package

I want to add a package in java to another package, so I added that package to my build path in eclipse and copied the .jar file to lib folder. But still my program does not recognize that added package. Kindly help.

Comment: are you trying to import the classes from the other package to your current package? an example perhaps?

Comment: Hi Sahar, The question asked is not very clear.. If you can put in some details, It would help us in resolving your issue. I am not sure what you mean by adding a package to another package. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

ok so i am assuming you want to import a class (or a set of classes) from a package into your class, correct?

if so, you need to add the jar to the buildPath and then add import statements in your class for the classes you want to include from that jar.
You can do a jar tvf  to see the list of classes present in that jar

so if your class is called MyView, in MyView.java you need to do:

```
import com.a.b
```

where the jar you added to the buildPath contains the class com.a.b